# Why I can't get to see my selected information on another page?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor, view

I'm working on a simple phone book and I'm trying to delete a Contact. When user presses the delete on Left picture it's information won't get to be shown (Right pic)

[image]

Here's my code in controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Delete(Models.EF_Model.Phone_book _Model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Ref_ViewModel = new ViewModel.ViewModel();
        Ref_ViewModel.Delete(_Model.Id);
    }
    else
    {
        ViewBag.Massage = "Choose a Contact";
    }
    return View();
}
```

This is my view

```
@model Project1.Models.EF_Model.Phone_book

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Delete";
}

<h2>Delete</h2>

<h3>Are you sure you want to delete this?</h3>
@ViewBag.Massage
<div>
    <h4>Phone_book</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Id)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Id)
        </dd>

         <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.First_Name)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.First_Name)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Last_Name)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Last_Name)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Number)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Number)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Email)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Address)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Address)
        </dd>

    </dl>

    @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
        <div class="form-actions no-color">
            <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-default" /> |
            @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Comment: You need to show the GET method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not returning any model to a view.

```
 return View(); <--- model is missing.
```

Should be

```
 var model = _someRepository.LoadPhoneBook(id);
 return View(model);
```

Comment: you mean in my [get] Method?

Comment: @MostafaBouzari You need it in your get and in your post method. If your post fails to delete due to invalid Modelstate, you still need to return model to your view, so it can render it again.